# A camada de Domínio deve depender de Infra Estrutura?

Tags: java, c#, ddd

Estou lendo o livro do Evans sobre DDD e me deparei com a seguinte citação:

> A camada de Infra não executa nenhuma ação sobre a camada de domínio, por estar abaixo dela, por estar abaixo ela não deve ter conhecimento específico sobre o domínio que está servindo.
>
> As Camadas de Aplicativo e Domínio chamam serviços fornecidos pela camada de Infra-Estrutura.

Lembrando que sou iniciante com DDD, e pelo que havia lido anteriormente a camada de domínio não deveria conhecer nenhuma outra camada, alguém poderia por gentileza mostrar alguma implementação mais próxima do que o Evans quis dizer neste ponto ou me corrigir se interpretei errado.

Comment: Felipe, coloque a referência completa do livro ou um link para algum lugar com a referência.

Comment: Não conhecer uma camada não significa não depender dela. Eu posso depender de alguém sem conhecer pessoalmente o meu bem-feitor, eu apenas sei o que ele faz por mim e sei como usufruir dos seus serviços. Por exemplo: o governo é meu bem-feitor e me fornece saúde quando eu preciso; para usufruir, eu só preciso saber chegar ao hospital. O workflow de atendimento, como os médicos são remunerados, como as máquinas de exame foram parar lá e como funcionam... são detalhes de implementação do hospital que eu não conheço e que podem mudar sem me afetar e sem eu sequer tomar conhecimento que mudaram.

Comment: Existem dois tipos de dependências, a direta e a indireta. A direta é o acoplamento explícito sem design, sem abstrações, etc. A indreta é a quela você não depende especificamente de um componente específico, você só precisa que alguém se comporte como tal e que te forneça o resultado que precisa, tanto faz quem ou qual seja. Agora essa analogia de governo ficou mais pra um acoplamento de 2 vias, o que nao certo. Nós dependemos de que alguém faça o  papel de médico, vai ser pago com dinheiro da mesma maneira: ou com impostos ou do nosso bolso. Basta respeitar contratos que as relações fluirão.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A camada de Domínio deve depender de Infra Estrutura?

Sim, a camada de Domínio depende da camada de Infra-Estrutura para realizar a persistência dos dados no banco de dados.

Porém, o que o DDD orienta é que as classes de Domínio **não sejam implementadas com referências diretas** a camada de Infra Estrutura.

Ou seja, no seu projeto responsável pelo Domínio (relacionado as regras de negócio) não coloque referências de banco de dados, NHibernate, .Net, threads, HTML5, javascript, etc.

Ao invés disso utilize **Serviços** externos que poderão ser reutilizados em vários pontos do sistema, exemplo:

1. No Domínio crie uma interface chamada IClienteServicoRepositorio contendo assinatura de métodos para Salvar, Excluir, Atualizar e Recuperar dados no banco
2. No projeto/camada de Infra Estrutura, implemente IClienteServicoRepositorio em uma classe ClienteServicoRepositorio, fazendo com que a Infra Estrutura tenha a implementação de como Salvar, Excluir, Atualizar e Recuperar no banco de dados objetos Cliente usando os repositórios

Com a classe ClienteServicoRepositorio na sua camada de Infra Estrutura implementando a interface IClienteServicoRepositorio definida no Dominio, agora vamos imaginar um cenário onde o seu Domínio vai depender de serviços de Infra Estrutura...

Supondo que preciso restringir exclusão de cliente devedor, posso incluir essa regra no Dominio e solicitar métodos da camada de Infra Estrutura, exemplo:

1. Criar uma classe no domínio chamada ClienteServico para serviços específicos relacionados a Cliente
2. Usar **Injeção de Dependência/Inversão de Controle** para manter o mínimo acoplamento entre as camadas de Dominino e Infra Estrutura

```c#
public class ClienteServico
{
    private readonly IClienteServicoRepositorio _clienteServicoRepositorio;

    public ClienteServico(IClienteServicoRepositorio clienteServicoRepositorio)
    {
       _clienteServicoRepositorio = clienteServicoRepositorio;
    }

    public ActionResult ExcluirCliente(Cliente cliente)
    {
       if(_clienteServicoRepositorio.ClienteDevedor(Cliente.Id))
       {
           RetornarMensagemExclusaoClienteDevedor();
       }
       //else ...
    }
}
```

Logo, temos um exemplo em que a camada Domínio chama serviços fornecidos pela camada de Infra-Estrutura com o mínimo acoplamento entre as camadas.

Comment: Boa resposta. Eu apenas não limitaria minhas preocupações a "referências diretas" ou uso de interfaces pois o conceito é um pouco mais profundo. Por exemplo, eu me sinto confortável em ter nas minhas entidades as anotações Hibernate que mapeiam os dados para tabelas no banco de dados. Então eu tenho no código de domínio duas preocupações diferentes (negócio e DB), mas, por diversos motivos que dariam um longo texto, eu ainda estou separando os conceitos e ainda estou usufruindo o melhor do DDD.

Comment: O dominio é o centro da aplicação, ele nao depende de nada diretamente além de ABSTRAÇÕES que o próprio domínio define, para que a camada de dados e infraestrutura forneçam  uma implementação que se adapta ao fluxo do domínio, e são repassadas por meio do principio da inversao de controle...

Comment: Sim todos nós já fizemos muito software acoplado, e funcionando bem por anos. Na vida real dependendo do prazo e requisitos do projeto, que muitas vezes não requerem o esforço para manter o software sempre preparado pra troca dce componentes, bancos de dados etc,  acaba que deixamos esse debito tecnico pra resolver depoiis. Conforme amadurecemos, naturalmente evitamos alguns code smells / bad designs.

Answer (score 1):

A camada de domínio não deve estar 'casada' com nenhuma outra camada, mas ela precisa chamar funções para CRUD na camada de persistência.

A ideia da camada de domínio não conhecer a camada de persistência (ou qualquer outra camada) é evitar 'casá-la' com uma implementação específica da camada de persistência. Entenda: fazer chamadas, sim, mas através de interfaces.

O citação acima trada de outro conceito. A camada de infra não pode fazer chamadas na camada de domínio. Nem por interface, nem sem. Quem faz as chamadas, quem orquestra tudo é a camada de domínio.

Assim, as duas ideias que vocês expos estão corretas, mas tratam sobre coisas diferentes (embora sigam a mesma filosofia de separação de conceitos).

---

Exemplos: Digamos que você tem a classe `UsersBL` para regras de negócio e a classe `UsersRepository` para persistência.

A classe `UsersBL` vai precisar chamar a classe `UsersRepository` para criação, busca, alteração dos dados.

**O primeiro conceito** que você citou diz que a classe `UsersRepository` não pode conter chamadas para a classe `UsersBL`. Por exemplo, poderia parecer útil usar uma função de validação que já está implementada e testada na classe `UsersBL`, mas isso é **errado**.

**O segundo conceito** diz que a classe `UsersBL` deve fazer chamadas na classe `UsersRepository`, claro, mas não deve fazer isso através de instâncias da classe `UsersRepository`. A classe no domínio deve usar interfaces.